# Why does the element's position change when rotating?

Tags: html, css, animation

When the element rotated , it is not in the middle and moves.

CSS:

```
div {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 16px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);
border-top: 16px solid rgb(83, 83, 192);
border-radius: 50%;
animation: loading 2s linear infinite;
transition-property: transform;
transform: translate(-50% , -50%);}

@-moz-kayframes loading {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
```

}

and HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

Comment: Your code is not animating, can you reproduce the issue for us and let us know what exactly the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are using `transform: translate(-50% , -50%);` to center your element but in your `@keyframes` you override `transform` by `rotation()` which overrides your `translate()`. If you would put `translate()` to animation too your div would be rotating around because `origin` (the anchor of rotation) would be different each frame.

So you can:
1) Center your element with `left` and `top` like this:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 16px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);
  border-top: 16px solid rgb(83, 83, 192);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: loading 2s linear infinite;
  /*transform: translate(-50% , -50%);*/
}

@keyframes loading {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

2) or use some parent element which will be centered and your animated div will be inside of it.

```css
.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 16px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);
  border-top: 16px solid rgb(83, 83, 192);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: loading 2s linear infinite;
}
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
}

@keyframes loading {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

---

+ I've deleted `transition-property` because you don't need it. You are using `animation` not `transition`.

Comment: How do I know how to put it in the middle? How much do I add or subtract? CSS:            calc (50% - 50px);

Comment: Because `100px` is `width` and `height` of element and `50px` half of it. You put element in `50%` of X and Y axis of window. So element will start (top-left corner) at 50% of parent/window. Than you have to substract half of the element height/width to get into the center.